# Tag badge mouseover: factor-of-ten error?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I just moused over a gold tag badge, and saw the popup

> Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the linux tag

But my understanding was that one needed at least a thousand *upvotes*, which would be *10,000* score (assuming score is reputation).  If it really does mean a thousand reputation, then the requirement is not merely that you've had a single upvote on each of a hundred answers, but that you have written a hundred more answers that weren't even worthy of a single upvote.  That's weird.

So it looks to me like the score requirement is under by a factor of ten.  The same is true of the mouseover text for the silver and bronze tag badges.

Or have I got the wrong end of this stick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Score, here, is total upvotes minus total downvotes.

As far as I know it's worked that way since (almost) the beginning.

To quote from the [SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/189912):

> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). Acceptance of an answer doesn't have any weight in the score. As well, posts which are in community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score. Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Ah, OK, that deals nicely with that; I had the wrong end of the stick.  Does that particular use of the word *score* crop up anywhere else on SF?  I can't help feeling that *net upvotes* would be a lot less mysterious a term.  Either way, thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: [Score](http://serverfault.com/help/search?q=score) is also used to refer to the net of upvotes and downvotes on a question or answer. It is not used anywhere else. In particular, _reputation_ is not referred to as score.

Comment: Fair enough.  I wouldn't have done that - as I said, *net upvotes* seems to me unambiguous and reuses an existing, well-understood term of art, which I find much better than defining a new term which is then hardly ever used - but it's not my site.